# How to prevent a page break between section title and colored rule?

Tags: sectioning, color, page-breaking, rules, titlesec

I use `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}` to customize the design of my sections, subsections...
In particular, i have :

```
\titleformat{\section}%
{\large\sffamily\bfseries}%
{My Section \arabic{section} }%
{0.5em}%
{#1}% \\ \hspace*{-1.5cm}
[{\color{blue}\titlerule[2.5pt]}]
```

where the `{\color{blue}\titlerule[2.5pt]}` produces an underline. The problem is, that a page breaking can happen just after the section title, and the line would appear on the next page. Is there a way to prevent that ?

EDIT : Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\titleformat{\section}%
{\large\sffamily\bfseries}%
{Section \arabic{section}}%
{0.5em}%
{#1}% \\ \hspace*{-1.5cm}
[{\color{blue}\titlerule[2.5pt]}]

\begin{document}

\section{titre1}
blabla  
\vspace{16cm}\\
blabla  
\section{titre2}
blabla blabla 
\end{document}
```

Comment: By default, LaTeX strongly discourages page breaks after sectioning commands. Therefore, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace `{\color{blue}<rule definition>}` with `\textcolor{blue}{<rule definition>}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\titleformat{\section}%
{\large\sffamily\bfseries}%
{Section \arabic{section}}%
{0.5em}%
{#1}% \\ \hspace*{-1.5cm}
[\textcolor{blue}{\titlerule[2.5pt]}]

\begin{document}

\section{titre1}
blabla  
\vspace{16cm}\\    blabla  
\section{titre2}
blabla blabla 
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Note that this solution produces unwanted additional vertical space between title and underline. See [Strange behaviour of titlesec, with colored titlerule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40088/strange-behaviour-of-titlesec-with-colored-titlerule) and particularly [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40089/510) for a solution to this follow-up problem.

Comment: ok, great! Thanks. But why does it works ?

Comment: Not sure, but `\color` is one of the commands that tend to disguise spacing commands and penalty values (here: the penalty for page breaks).

Comment: I just noticed a annoying thing : with \textcolor instead of \color, this prevents the pagebreaking, but on the other hand, the vertical space between the text and the underline is increased...

Comment: @nicolasroy I've no idea right now what causes this. Perhaps `titlesec` allows to add some negative vertical space to correct the observed effect. If nothing helps, please ask a follow-up question.

Comment: @lockstep: the reason why `\color` introduces a break point is because it calls a `\write` which introduces a whatsit. You can see this by replacing `{\color{blue}\titlerule[2.5pt]}` with `{\write-1{}\titlerule[2.5pt]}`. To solve the problem, no need for `\textcolor`, `{\color{blue}\nobreak\titlerule[2.5pt]}` is enough.