# Strange behaviour of titlesec, with colored titlerule

Tags: spacing, sectioning, color, titlesec

With the following MWE, i get the Section title underlined in black :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\titleformat{\section}%
{\large\sffamily\bfseries}%
{Section \arabic{section}}%
{0.5em}%
{#1}%
[{\titlerule[2.5pt]}]

\begin{document}
\section{mon titre}
\end{document}
```

My first problem : if i remove the `{ }` enclosing `\titlerule`, i get a compilation error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}
```

Which is strange, since the content of the `[ ]` is a text to typeset after the section title. For example

```
[some-after-text]
```

works.
My second problem : if i colorize the rule with

```
[\textcolor{blue}{\titlerule[2.5pt]}]
```

I obtain a blue underline, but with an additional vertical space (app 0.5 cm) between the title and the underline.
If i use

```
[{\color{blue}\titlerule[2.5pt]}]
```

instead, the vertical space disappears... I have to admit, i do not understand that.

Comment: To see why `\textcolor` starts a new paragraph (mentioned in @egreg's answer), add `\makeatletter\show\@textcolor\makeatother` after `\titleformat`, then inspect your `.log` file and see that it executes `\leavevmode` (`\@textcolor` is just a subsidiary function called by `\textcolor`). Then read [Function and usage of `\leavevmode`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22852/5764).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not strange: without the braces, in the first case, the first closing `]` is matched with the opening `[` that announces the optional argument to `\titleformat`. An optional argument always goes from the `[` to the first `]` (at the same brace level).

The second problem is due to the fact that `\textcolor` starts a paragraph, while `\color` doesn't. But, as you already discovered, using `\color` inserts a break point and the rule may go on the following page.

Solution:

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {Section \arabic{section}}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  [\titleline{\color{blue}\titlerule[2.5pt]}]
```