# How can I set a color for the title rule?

Tags: sectioning, color, titlesec

I'm writing a document which uses titlesec, and I'd like to set the title rule to a different color.

How can I do that?

This is what I currently have, which produces section titles with black rules:

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\Large\sffamily}
{\thesection.}{.5em}{}[\titlerule]
```

Note: I want to change the color of the rule that appears below a section title.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's difficult to say without an example of the code you're using and an indication of *what* rule you want to color.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a very simple manner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\Large\sffamily}
{\thesection.}{.5em}{}[\color{red}\titlerule]

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\vspace{5cm}
\section{Hello again}
\end{document}
```

I add the resulting image of my code:

[image]

> **EDIT**

As @lockstep noticed, to avoid that `\color` inserts break points ([reference answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40088/strange-behaviour-of-titlesec-with-colored-titlerule/40089#40089)) should be better to use:

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\Large\sffamily}
{\thesection.}{.5em}{}[\titleline{\color{red}\titlerule}]
```